# Setting UIPicker view to selected string - Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Is there a way to set a UIPicker view to a selected string? My picker view is populated from a database and contains a set of names. I want to set the value of the view to a selected name when it is populated. The row number will change every time. Is it possible to set the value to match a string?

Below is my attempt based on the comments:

```
            var i : Int = 0
        while (nameArray[i] != assetArray[0].Owner)
        {
            i=i+1
        }
        scroll_owners.selectRow(i, inComponent: i, animated: true)
```

This causes the code to break when trying to load it due to Index out of bounds.

Comment: set it's selectedindex property

Comment: first iterate array and match string and find that string index.

Comment: @SumitDhariwal Hi, I've added some code following your suggestion... any idea on why it's erroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying the correct approach but need to implement in another way.
Try this:

```
    let index = self.nameArray.index(where: {$0 == assetArray[0].Owner })
    scroll_owners.selectRow(index ?? 0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

**Note:** Pass the correct value for `inComponent`, if your picker view have only one column then it'll work fine.

Comment: The following error is thrown when trying this code: 2017-11-15 14:10:09.708174 AssetManagement[3838:639001] -[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x123d3d700

Comment: I do only have one column - the value of index is being set as nil when debugging.

Comment: make sure do your `nameArray` contains the value of `assetArray[0].Owner`?

Comment: It definitely does contain it as I added to the assetArray using the selected value from the picker and then tried to search for it once it had been added.

Comment: The index being returned by this method is 6178617024  - there are only around 70 items in my array so this doesn't make sense?

Comment: It's working fine for me, try this code in playground: let nameArray = ["owl", "finch", "sparrow", "eagle", "card1","card2","card3","card4","card5","card6","card7","card8","card9","card10","card11","card12","card13"]

let index = nameArray.index(where: {$0 == "card13" })

print(index ?? 0) //16

let index1 = nameArray.index(where: {$0 == "finch" })
print(index1 ?? 0) //1

Comment: There might be some other issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159070/discussion-between-pramod-kumar-saxena-and-benjiiiii).